# Visual Basic using Drawline - draw 3 lines using a loop

Tags: vb.net

I need to draw three uniform lines of a random length that are at least big enough so the lines can be seen. The max length should be about the size of a button. The three lines should be drawn under the button. I have to use a loop. I have a basic code for 1 line, but how to turn it into a loop with the above requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to determine your spacing, and setup some variables for your Start Position and the Length use the Random.Next method to set your length within the parameters that you choose. See if something like this works for you.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    drawLine()
End Sub


Private Sub drawLine()
    Dim g As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
    Dim spacing As Integer = 5
    Dim xStart As Integer = 50 ''Start of line
    Dim xEnd As Integer  'End of Line
    Dim minLength As Integer = 10
    Dim maxLength As Integer = 70
    Dim rndm As New Random
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim y As Integer = 50 'Top of first Line
    g.Clear(Me.BackColor) 'Reset Drawing

    Do Until (i = 3)
        xEnd = rndm.Next(minLength, maxLength)
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, New Point(xStart, y), New Point(xStart + xEnd, y))
        y += spacing
        i += 1
    Loop
    g.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! How do i get them to be the same size though.. once it picks a random size to be? So with that random size all 3 are the same length. I tried playing with this line xEnd = rndm.Next(minLength, maxLength)    but no luck

Comment: @Cliff assign the random to the xEnd before you enter the loop.

Comment: ah, ok.. what an easy fix. Thanks again.

Comment: The lines drawn using this method will disappear if the form is repainted or minimized or if another window is dragged across it.  The CreateGraphics call should be avoided.  The drawing should be performed in the OnPaint override or Paint event.